# Ground Truth datasets for Evaluating Open Source NLP tools for Named Entity Recognition

Tags: dataset, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on building a document similarity graph for a collection. I already do all the basic things like tokenization, stemming, stop-word removal, and bag-of-word representation to represent the documents and computing similarity using Jaccard coefficient. I am now trying to extract Named Entities and evaluate if these would be helpful in improving the quality of the document similarity graph.  I have been spending much of time on finding ground-truth datasets for my analysis. I have been very disappointed with Message Understanding Conference (MUC) datasets. They are cryptic to understand and requires sufficient data cleaning/massaging before it can be used on a different platform (like Scala)

My questions are here more specifically

1. Are there tutorials on getting started with MUC datasets that would make it easier for analyzing the results using open source NLP tools like openNLP
2. there other datasets available?
3. Tools like OpenNLP and Stanford Core NLP employ approaches that are essentially supervised. Correct?
4. GATE is a great tool for hand-annotating your own text corpus Correct?
5. For a new test dataset (that I hand-create) how can I compute the baseline (Vocabulary Transfer) or what kind of metrics can I compute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have a few concerns about using Jaccard coefficient to compute similarity. I'd expect TF.IDF and cosinus similarity to give better results.

Some answers to your questions:

2. See the [CoNLL 203 evaluation campaign](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/): it also provides data, evaluation tools, etc. You ma also have a look at [ACE](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2003T11).
3. Yes
4. Gate is also a pipeline that automatically annotates text, but as far as I know NER is a rule-based component.
5. A baseline is most of the time a very simple algorithm (e.g. majority classes) so it is not a baseline to compare corpus, but to compare approaches.

Comment: Thanks eldams for your response. I have tried TF-IDF and Cosine as well. Jaccard is more robust than Cosine. Regarding point 5) What do you mean by majority classes in terms of NER?

Comment: Majority classes are when you give for any token the class that has been the most frequently associatedfwith the token in training dataset. It gives a simple yet quite accurate baseline for less ambiguous tokens. The overall performance depends on the amount of ambiguity and oov (out-of-vocabulary) tokens in test dataset.